# How to pass friendlyname instead of urn:oid in saml response

Tags: ldap, saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth, simplesamlphp

I am trying to send saml response from  my shibboleth idp to a service provider

How can I  pass the  friendlyname instead of urn:oid in saml response? Right now, my saml response contains the urn:oid only,

for instance,  'urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.6': '106',

what I need to to pass is a key called "productid" along with this response,

'productid: '106',

below given is my attribute-resolver.xml where I've passed the friendlyName as productid for roomNumber(urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.6)

```
<resolver:AttributeDefinition id="productid" xsi:type="ad:Simple" sourceAttributeID="roomNumber">
        <resolver:Dependency ref="myLDAP" />
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML1String" name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:roomNumber" encodeType="false" />
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.6" friendlyName="productid" encodeType="false" />
    </resolver:AttributeDefinition>
```

Can I please get some insights into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc for SAML2 String](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/SAML2StringAttributeEncoder) looks like you should be able to do:

```
<resolver:AttributeDefinition id="productid" xsi:type="ad:Simple" sourceAttributeID="roomNumber">
        <resolver:Dependency ref="myLDAP" />
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML1String" name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:roomNumber" encodeType="false" />
        <resolver:AttributeEncoder xsi:type="enc:SAML2String" name="productid" friendlyName="productid" encodeType="false" />
</resolver:AttributeDefinition>
```

although you're encouraged to [make sure the attribute is unique by its scope](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/AttributeNaming).